# data.table update join using a constant

Tags: r, performance, join, data.table

I'd like to update a subset of rows in a data.table based on a join and a fixed value.

```
d1 <- data.table(A = 5:1, B = letters[5:1])    
d2 <- data.table(C = letters[5:1], Z = 6:10)
current.val <- 5
```

what i want to do is update d1 based on the join with d2, but only where where A==5 in d1. something like this:

```
d1[d2, D := i.Z ,on=.(B==C, A==current.val)]
```

my current approach is a add a new column to d2 and set it to the fixed value and use that in the join:

```
d2[, current.val := 5]
d1[d2, D := i.Z ,on=.(B==C, A==current.val)]
```

This works, but seem like a lot of overhead. Is there a simpler way to use a constant value in a join?

---

(8/14) New scale example for benchmarking:

```
d1 <- data.table(A = 100:1, B = 100000000:1, D = as.numeric(NA),  key = c("A", "B"))
d2 <- data.table(C = 100000000:1, Z = c(10:1) / 10, key = "C")
current.val <- 5

system.time(d1[cbind(d2, A = current.val), on = .(B = C, A), D := i.Z])
system.time({setkey(d1, B, A); d1[d1[d2][A == current.val], D := Z]; setkey(d1, A, B)})
system.time(d1[d1[d2][A == current.val], D := Z]) # fastest, if inverse key order is acceptable
```

Comment: Your solution looks simple enough.  If you don't want to create a column, then use the row index, i.e. `i1 <- d1[, .I[A==current.val]];
d1[i1, D:= d1[i1][d2, i.Z[i1], on = .(B==C)]]`

Comment: Not sure if you're benchmarking the right thing there. I am getting "Error in vecseq [...] Join results in more than 2^31 rows" for the second one.

Comment: Frank, see comments on answer from @gcbenison below. Ill update the post to reflect the working benchmark

Answer (score 1):

> my current approach is a add a new column to d2 and set it to the fixed value and use that in the join [...] Is there a simpler way to use a constant value in a join?

That's a good way to go. Alternately, you could add a column temporarily inside the join with `cbind`:

```
d1[cbind(d2, A = current.val), on=.(B = C, A), D := i.Z ]
```

Actually, `c` works in place of `cbind` here, but I find it a weirder approach.

Comment: I like this better than my current approach. it scopes the additional column to its purpose. i still feel like i'm missing something in not being able to filter directly on a constant

Comment: @Ethan To filter on a constant, I usually do `d1[.(current.val), on=.(A)]`. I guess eventually it may be possible to write a constant into `on=`, but it's a fairly new feature right now... also, I'm not sure I like the idea so much, design-wise, since it's nice to have all data relevant to the `x[i]` join in either `x` or `i`.

Comment: Right. its the added complexity of the writeback using  `:=` that makes this more complex. Something i have been struggling with on `data.table` in general is that subsetting rules don't always work the same way in the context of the writeback `:=` operator.

Comment: @Ethan I think the rules are consistent, but it may be hard to get the intuition, since the subsetting is sometimes a simple subset and other times a join. Unfortunately, there is not a joins vignette published yet, but maybe my notes will be helpful if you want to build intuition: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#tables

Comment: look, I **love** dt and am very thankful to Matt et al for building it and to the community for all the help. i think we've crossed paths on this before;) https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/614 , but I very much appreciate your insights and help

Answer (score 0):

For just five rows, it won't make any difference, but if you want to scale up then this operation will be much faster if you set keys on `d1` and `d2`:

```
d1 <- data.table(A=5:1, B=letters[5:1], key="B")
d2 <- data.table(C=letters[5:1], Z=6:10, key="C")
```

The following construct will then give the desired result:

```
d1[d1[d2][A==current.val], D := Z]
```

Comment: very interesting approach. i wasn't sure how dt would optimize the cross-join/filter/join, so I updated the example to allow benchmarking. The solution (as presented based on the initial example) will not complete with the bigger input set. Also the key on d1 is really be A,B. Also possible i messed up the new example ;)

Comment: With the new example (1e8 rows) - I had to change the key of `d1` from (A, B) to (B, A) for this to work.  With that change it gives the expected result in about 5 seconds on my system.

Comment: so, did some testing. for my real world case, i need the key as A,B. I tried adding an index `setindex(d1,B,A)` but that didn't work.  I don't really understand why it works with a key , but not an index, but that's a separate issue.  while this solution is much faster on its own, benchmarks for switching the key `system.time({setkey(d1, B, A); d1[d1[d2][A == current.val], D := Z]; setkey(d1, A, B)})` are about the same as for the temp column approach