# r - Efficiently create variable indicating if date variable precedes event (by group)

Tags: r, date, group-by, dplyr, data.table

I have two dates (`date1` and `date2`) and an `id` variable in a data.frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(c('2014-02-11', '2014-05-04', '2014-05-22'), c('2014-04-12', '2014-09-22', '2014-07-04'), c('a', 'a', 'b'))
names(dat) <- c('date1', 'date2', 'id')
dat$date1 <- as.character.Date(dat$date1, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
dat$date2 <- as.character.Date(dat$date2, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
> dat
       date1      date2 id
1 2014-02-11 2014-04-12  a
2 2014-05-04 2014-09-22  a
3 2014-05-22 2014-07-04  b
```

I would like to create a new variable `var` that indicates whether **any** `date2` date value precedes the `date1` date value for that row (not simply the `date2` value immediately preceding it):

```
> dat
       date1      date2 id var
1 2014-02-11 2014-04-12  a   0
2 2014-05-04 2014-09-22  a   1
3 2014-05-22 2014-07-04  b   0
```

I've been able to achieve this with the following loop:

```
ids <- as.vector(unique(unlist(dat$id)))
dat$var <- as.numeric(0)
for (i in ids) {
  date2s <- as.vector(unlist(filter(dat, id == i)$date2))
  for (j in date2s) {
    dat <- dat %>% mutate(var = replace(var, (j < date1) & (id == i), 1)) # if any cdate precedes rdate
  }
}
```

However, my data set is quite large, and I would like to achieve this using `data.table` if possible, though I'm happy to approach this with `dplyr` if there's an efficient approach.

Comment: you mean `date1 > min(date2)`?

Comment: I mean if there exists any `date2` value less than the `date1` value in a given row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the other three answers so far...

```
library(data.table)

frank_first = function() dat[, v0 := as.logical(copy(.SD)[copy(.SD), on=.(id, date2 < date1), mult="first", .N, by=.EACHI]$N)]

frank_which = function() dat[, vw := !is.na(copy(.SD)[copy(.SD), on=.(id, date2 < date1), mult="first", which=TRUE])]

frank_any = function() dat[, v1 := .SD[copy(.SD), on=.(id, date2 < date1), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L]

frank_min = function() dat[, v := as.logical(.SD[, min(date2), by=id][copy(.SD), on=.(id, V1 < date1), .N, by=.EACHI]$N)]

fun = function(x, y) x > min(y)
mtm <- function(df) {
    df$var <- NA  # new column, to be updated
    split(df$var, df$id) <-
        Map(fun, split(df$date1, df$id), split(df$date2, df$id))
    df
}
```

The `copy` stuff is needed due to [an open issue/bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926).

A benchmark with chinsoon + Martin Morgan's data:

```
set.seed(2L)
N <- 1e5
ng = 1e4
dat <- data.table(date1=sample(seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by="1 day"), N, replace=TRUE), 
    date2=sample(seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by="1 day"), N, replace=TRUE),
    id=sample(ng, N, replace=TRUE))

df = data.frame(dat)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(frank_first(), frank_which(), frank_any(), frank_min(), mtm(df), times=5L)

Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 frank_first()  70.38654  70.72610  80.37284  73.33607  86.87363 100.54186     5  a 
 frank_which()  55.90631  57.16385  62.89525  61.82535  64.63895  74.94178     5  a 
   frank_any()  38.56254  39.42893  40.53816  39.85976  41.47074  43.36885     5  a 
   frank_min()  36.73850  36.90551  62.55768  45.44839  55.41056 138.28545     5  a 
       mtm(df) 186.44924 190.26654 209.38918 219.73829 224.06300 226.42884     5   b
```

So the min way (motivated by Martin Morgan's answer) wins with this example data.

Comment: This is just a variation on thelatemail's answer, but I'm posting at OP's request.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but this preserves the rest of the data.table (assuming there are other variables), and is therefore more practical.

Comment: If I wanted to expand on the conditions that need to be met for the new variable to be equal to 1, how would I do so? I would need to add this to `i`, correct?

Comment: I attempt to add another indicator variable (I want this to be equal to 1) to `on` as `on = .(id, date2 < date1, var2)` and I receive the error: `Error in set(nqx <- shallow(x), j = "_nqgrp_", value = nqgrp)`

Comment: Yeah, that error is unfortunate... I think it is related to the issue/bug I linked. Wrapping `copy(.SD)` instead of `.SD` usually fixes it in my experience. Yeah, another var should work with definition in `on=`. You might also need/want to use `cbind` for it as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45663715/ If we can't figure it out in comments, you could post a new question, of course.

Comment: Hi @Frank, in terms of scoping is the 2nd .SD with respect to the 2nd [ or still with respect to the 1st [? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @chinsoon12 It's with respect to the first. The way I keep track of it is: `.SD` can only appear in the `j` part of a `DT[...]` call, so if we're referring to it in `i`, it must refer to the `.SD` from one level up.

Comment: @Frank, got it. Thanks so much!

Comment: FWIW coercing date to numeric helps the base R implementation quite a bit, I updated my response with this.

Answer (score 6):

A suggestion to use `.EACHI` as follows after a self-join as suggested by @thelatemail

```
dat[dat, .(date1=i.date1, date2=i.date2, var=any(date2 < i.date1)), by=.EACHI, on=.(id)]

#   id      date1      date2   var
#1:  a 2014-02-11 2014-04-12 FALSE
#2:  a 2014-05-04 2014-09-22  TRUE
#3:  b 2014-05-22 2014-07-04 FALSE
```

---

Edit: some timing for reference

```
set.seed(2L)
N <- 1e5
dat <- data.table(date1=sample(seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by="1 day"), N, replace=TRUE), 
    date2=sample(seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by="1 day"), N, replace=TRUE),
    id=sample(letters, N, replace=TRUE))

dt1 <- copy(dat)
tlmMtd <- function() {
    dt1[, rownum := .I]
    dt1[dt1[dt1, on="id", rownum[i.date2 < date1], allow.cartesian=TRUE], hit := 1]
}

dt2 <- copy(dat)
csMtd <- function() dt2[dt2, .(date1=i.date1, date2=i.date2, var=any(date2 < i.date1)), by=.EACHI, on=.(id)]


dt3 <- copy(dat)
frankMtd <- function() dt3[, v := .SD[copy(.SD), on=.(id, date2 < date1), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    tlmMtd(),
    csMtd(),
    frankMtd(),
    times=5L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
# tlmMtd()   18528.9799 18652.2217 23486.4213 19116.8014 21140.5923 39993.511     5
# csMtd()     3801.2146  3943.6201  4984.6274  5341.4322  5673.6878  6163.182     5
# frankMtd()   176.4477   177.5576   191.9636   178.9564   182.0311   244.825     5
```

Comment: I think this will be quicker than my effort because `.EACHI` shouldn't have to return the results of the join before doing the calculation. I just got in a tangle trying to get it to work.

Comment: @thelatemail i got into a tangle trying to use `.EACHI`. never used it before and return a lot of stuff and figuring out if i should i. or dont i. or even :=. need to learn more

Comment: Thanks for this @chinsoon12 but it drops all other variables in the data.table since you're selecting specific columns (problematic if applying this to non-toy data).

Comment: the number of upvotes is misleading...please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063024/r-efficiently-create-variable-indicating-if-date-variable-precedes-event-by-g/49074581#49074581

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this is doable through a self-join in `data.table`. E.g.:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)
dat[, rownum := .I]
dat[dat[dat, on="id", rownum[i.date2 < date1]], hit := 1]
dat

#        date1      date2 id rownum hit
#1: 2014-02-11 2014-04-12  a      1  NA
#2: 2014-05-04 2014-09-22  a      2   1
#3: 2014-05-22 2014-07-04  b      3  NA
```

I essentially create a row reference number, then join the table on itself `on` `"id"`, find the rows where the date comparison is as expected, then use those row numbers to assign the final `hit` variable.

Comment: A different self join: `dat[, v := .SD[copy(.SD), on=.(id, date2 < date1), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L]` The `copy` is needed thanks to an open issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926

Comment: When I attempt the suggestion by @thelatemail I receive the following error: `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 546303250 rows; more than 2304900 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE.`

Comment: Given that message, I tried the suggestion made by @Frank which worked. However, the resulting variable is a logical. How would I turn this into an indicator variable?

Comment: @kathystehl Well, a logical *is* an indicator variable :) However, if you want 0/1 in place of false/true, `as.integer` should do that, like `dat[, v := as.integer(.SD[copy(.SD), on=.(id, date2 < date1), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L)]`

Comment: Ha! Yes, yes I guess it is. Thanks @Frank! I didn't realize you could generate a new variable like that with `data.table` (I'm slowly trying to convert from `dplyr`). Can you please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4):

Neither data.table nor dplyr, but start by writing a function that does what you want assuming the columns are not grouped

```
function(x, y)
    as.Date(x) > min(as.Date(y))
```

Then use `split()` to divide the data into groups, `Map()` to apply the function to each group, and `split<-()` to assign the new value

```
answer <- logical(nrow(dat))
split(answer, dat$id) <-
    Map(fun, split(dat$date1, dat$id), split(dat$date2, dat$id))
```

This will be relatively efficient, even with large data, provided there are not too many groups. Not sure why dates were converted to character in the sample data; `fun()` could be generalized otherwise.

For timing using the data in @chinsoon12 (where in fact there are only a few groups), I have

```
df <- as.data.frame(dat)
mtm1 <- function(df) {
    answer <- logical(nrow(dat))
    split(answer, df$id) <-
        Map(fun, split(df$date1, df$id), split(df$date2, df$id))
    answer
}
```

with

```
> identical(mtm1(df), frankMtd()$v)
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(frankMtd(), mtm(df), times=5L)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min        lq       mean     median         uq        max
 frankMtd() 1917.95697 1927.2548 1928.65821 1928.45893 1933.34159 1936.27878
   mtm1(df)   47.00293   47.0198   48.02849   47.10012   47.18432   51.83523
 neval cld
     5   b
     5  a
```

If there are 1000 groups (`id = sample(1000, N, replace = TRUE)`), then the timings are more even

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 frankMtd() 140.87859 140.88647 141.97093 141.86977 142.28619 143.9336     5
   mtm1(df)  61.82032  64.55505  64.61313  65.53642  65.53768  65.6162     5
 cld
   b
  a
```

A considerable speedup can be had by vectorized coercion of Date values to  numeric

```
mtm2 <- function(df) {
    answer <- logical(nrow(df))
    split(answer, df$id) <- Map(
        function(x, y) x > min(y),
        split(as.numeric(df$date1), df$id),
        split(as.numeric(df$date2), df$id)
    )
    answer
}
```

with 1e5 values in 1e4 groups, with `id` a factor(), and in comparison to the  fastest `frank_*()`, results are

```
> identical(frank_any()$v, mtm1(df))
[1] TRUE
> identical(frank_any()$v, mtm2(df))
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 frank_any()  79.90262  80.43112  81.79228  81.18565  83.18963  84.25236     5
    mtm1(df) 237.00027 241.40299 244.83638 246.26495 249.47713 250.03658     5
    mtm2(df)  44.11074  46.17133  51.26976  47.03285  52.77204  66.26184     5
 cld
  b 
   c
 a
```

Comment: If you're using chinsoon12's data, you don't need the `as.Date` conversion in `fun`. Btw, it looks like if I compute `min`, it cuts the time back down in favor of the non-equi join: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41465718#41465718

Comment: @Frank Its the kind of operation that data.table should be fast at, so I'm not surprised that there are implementations that are faster than base R. I can't actually read the data.table syntax, and the overall strategy in base R -- write a function to do the job, then figure out how to do it on groups (typically `split() <- lapply(split(), fun)` or the twist in this case using `Map()`) seems to be pretty general and reasonably fast, so a good tool to have in hand.

Comment: Yeah, it's a very good tool and easy to read. I always forget about `split<-`. I only thought as far as whether I could do it cleanly with `ave` and when I couldn't, gave up and went to data.table.